# Populate Datatable with json values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I'm making a database search and returns a json. I'm trying display this data using datatable but without success.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="5%"></th>
            <th width="5%">Id</th>
            <th width="10%">Cat</th>
            <th width="15%">Name</th>
            <th width="5%">Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var data = dados.responseJSON[2].Value[0];

settings.myTable.DataTable({
    data: dados.responseJSON[2].Value[0], 
    columns: [
        { data: 'Id' },
        { data: 'Id' },
        { data: 'Cat' },
        { data: 'Name' },
        { data: 'Code' },        
    ]

    /****************
         WHAT MORE??
     *****************\

});
```

My variable `data` is the `ajax` success, when I do `console.log` in `data` I can see the values. Have all json objects and is the exactly name inside my `th` tables.

I think that I need insert something code more to populate the table. When I run this code isn't returned any error.

What wrong I'm doing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have data from your json in the format of array of objects,
e.g:

```
var data=
    [
        {
            "name":    "Tiger shroff",
            "place":   "Mumbai",
            "salary":   "3,00,00,000",
            "age":      "27",
            "office":   "Lower Parel",
            "id":       "120"
        },
        {
            "name":    "Salman Khan",
            "place":   "Central Jail",
            "salary":   "1,00,00,000",
            "age":      "51",
            "office":   "Mumbai",
            "id":       "420"
        }
    ]
```

Now you can define your columns in datatable function as per keys in the object.

```
$('#table').DataTable( {
data: data,
columns: [
      { data: 'name' },
      { data: 'place' },
      { data: 'salary' },
      { data: 'id' }
    ]
});
```